# (MT5210) Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _GULIsLoggableLevel. Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, mobile

Today I try to download from nuget package manager MarcTron to use Ads in my app and when I try to run the project in debug mode I receive this error:

```
Error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _GULIsLoggableLevel. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in. (MT5210) (WeatherLocationInfo.iOS)
```

Another error is:

```
APMMeasurement networkUploadCompletionHandlerWithResponse: Error: ] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement_7b399ffe8f030717675febfa49640b5b.o) (WeatherLocationInfo.iOS)
```

When I delete the library everything is ok.

The same error I receive when I try to download Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds.

How can I fix this issues ?

Comment: Nothing to contribute besides I too am also getting this error adding the latest Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds to my Xamarin ios project.